# ElixirLS compiles without OTP EEP48 docs

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, language-server-protocol, asdf-vm

Recently I had problem that I can't solve. It's about Elixir LS, when I run language server, it displays this message:

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"message":"Started ElixirLS v0.12.0","type":3}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"message":"ElixirLS built with elixir \"1.14.2\" on OTP \"25\"","type":3}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"message":"Running on elixir \"1.14.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)\" on OTP \"25\"","type":3}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/showMessage","params":{"message":"OTP compiled without EEP48 documentation chunks","type":2}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"message":"OTP compiled without EEP48 documentation chunks. Language features for erlang modules will run in limited mode. Please reinstall or rebuild OTP with approperiate flags.","type":2}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"message":"Elixir sources not found (checking in /home/build/elixir). Code navigation to Elixir modules disabled.","type":3}}
```

ElixirLS can't compile correctly, as it says, it compiles without EEP48 documentation.
I followed guide on ElixirLS installation, but I can't make it work.
Erlang and elixir are installed with asdf, i'm running Elixir 1.14.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25) on Arch Linux.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [Getting Erlang documentation](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang/blob/0d402e65a1328ed06c7920184f9806acfe251213/README.md#getting-erlang-documentation) section of the `asdf-erlang` docs, especially:

```bash
export KERL_BUILD_DOCS="yes"
```

and

> **Note:** Environment variable has to be set before `asdf install erlang <version>` is executed, to take effect.

Comment: I fixed it last night, but I can't fix "Elixir sources not found (checking in /home/build/elixir). Code navigation to Elixir modules disabled." error.